# sed/awk/grep print next line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file:

```
Bin674  chr04   32.003  32.09
Bin671  chr04   31.612  31.632
```

And file b:

```
Bin670  Chr04   31.553  31.612
Bin671  Chr04   31.612  31.632
Bin672  Chr04   31.632  31.673
Bin673  Chr04   31.673  32.003
Bin674  Chr04   32.003  32.09
Bin675  Chr04   32.09   32.159
Bin676  Chr04   32.159  32.196
```

I want to print `Bin673` line and `Bin675` line and `Bin671` line and `Bin672` line
Just, the line in file a Previous line and Next line:
how to write in shell?

Comment: What did try on your own?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: the code sed -n '/Bin674/{n;p}'  file b;But if file a have many rows,write them one by one?

Comment: @陈泽宇 Clarify your **question** it is not so hard to answer. But your question is not clear enough what pattern you need

Answer (score 1):

Well, this will give you what you are looking. I have taken files name as a and b. Now, reading the file a and getting the first word then printing the previous and next line for the matching word in file b.

```
for word in $(< a awk '{split($0, word, " "); print word[1]}'); do out=$(grep "$word" -A1 -B1 b | grep -v "$word"); echo "$out"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep Bin673 -A1 -B1 b`

- `-An` displays `n` lines after the match
- `-Bn` displays `n` lines before the match

Example:

```
$ grep Bin673 -A1 -B1 b

Bin672  Chr04   31.632  31.673
Bin673  Chr04   31.673  32.003
Bin674  Chr04   32.003  32.09
```

Comment: But may be file a have many rows,I must write one by one?thanks

Comment: grep has a regex mode where you can use `'term1|term2|term3'`

Comment: I know this,may be 100 rows ,may be it's difficult write regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's:^(\S+\s).*:/\\n\1/{p;n;p}:' patternFile | sed -ne 'N' -f - dataFile
```

Turn the pattern  file into a sed script and using a window of two lines match on the second line, then print the following line too.